# Can you get Anomen back, if you fail to investigate his sister's death?

Tags: baldurs-gate-2

I am playing BG2:EE on the iPad, and its wonderful to relive some of the stories and battles that I have when I originally played it as a younger teen. With Anomen, I had forgotten that some quests are truly time sensitive, so he left the party while I was in the middle of exploring a dungeon, and the quest log indicated the quest as a "Done quest" for Anomen, noting that he simply went back to his home in the Gov District to investigate his sister's murder.

My question is - is there any way that I could get him back in the party so I could continue this story line? I searched through many forums about his quest for knighthood, but it doesn't seem like many people were stuck at the murder stage?

Thanks!

Comment: While I assume the answer is no and you need to reload, have you checked at his family home? It's a long shot but he might be there and allow you to pick up the quest.

Comment: Thanks @Studoku - I did check his home in the Gov district, but cannot head inside as it is quest-locked.

Comment: In which case the only other thing I can suggest would be console commands and I'm afraid I don't know the Baldurs Gate console well enough.